# matrix of characters in c , I need to pass a matrix to a function as a parameter

Tags: c, matrix, char

I need to pass a matrix to a function as a parameter but when checking if it is happening or not I try to print the value of the `matrix [1][1]` and it does not work

```
int Cabe_proceso(int pag, int cel,int pal,char Memoria_fisica[1][pal-1]){  

  printf("[%s]\n",Memoria_fisica[1][1]);  
}  
int main(void){

    int palabras, celdas;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras soportadas por la memoria principal\n");

    scanf("%i",&palabras);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que define el tamano de un marco de paginas\n");

    scanf("%i",&celdas);
    int marcos =palabras/celdas;
    int i,j,aux=celdas,m=1;
    if(palabras%celdas ==0){
        marcos= marcos;
    }else{
        marcos++;
    }

    char *Memoria_fisica[1][palabras-1];
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<palabras;j++){
            Memoria_fisica[i][j]= "0";
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<palabras;j++){
            printf("[%s]\n",Memoria_fisica[i][j]);
            if(j==aux-1){
                printf("--------------marco %i\n", m);
                aux=aux+celdas;
                m++;
            }

        }
        if(palabras%celdas!=0){
            printf("------------------marco %i\n",marcos);
        }

    }
    printf("%i\n",celdas);
    Cabe_proceso(1,celdas,palabras,Memoria_fisica);

    return 0;
}
```

I included the bookstores **stdio.h** , **stdlib.h**, **strings.h**

Comment: You're accessing memory outside the array: `printf("[%s]\n",Memoria_fisica[1][1]); `.  `Memoria_fisica` only has one element at index `0`.

Comment: Bookstores == Libraries?

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes libraries

Comment: I dont unserstand your first comment, please tell me how fix it, because 
probe with printing the value [1] [3] and it does not work either @FiddlingBits

Comment: `Memoria_fisica` doesn't have index at `1`, only at `0`. Try: `Memoria_fisica[0][n]`

Comment: What is it your program does?

Comment: In C array indexing is `0` based. So `char a[2];` has the two elements `a[0]` and `a[1]`.